# "How to build a chatbot with anuglar and node.js"?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am a newbie, I would like to know is it possible to build our own chatbot with angular and node.js? or What are all the information and technologies do i need to know to build my own customized chatbot?

Comment: Well... Yes, it's possible to build a chatbot with Angular and Node.js. That's the only answer you can have there. You'll need to learn Angular and Node.js to achieve that.

Comment: Angular is an MVC framework, it will hardly be useful in coding a bot. I'd suggest researching existing bots ; most will likely be coded in C-derivatives or python, but you might be able to find a node.js one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you must know how does it actually work, i have written one in C# [Chatbot using c#](https://cscodez.blogspot.in/2013/06/chatbot-using-c.html) that can give you a basic idea, but proficiency in Javascript is must before you dig deep into these things.

Once you understand it you can go/learn the [Artificial Intelligence Markup Language](http://www.alicebot.org/aiml.html) which is implemented on [ALICE bot](http://www.alicebot.org/). There is also a new offering from Microsoft called [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) which can also be used with node.js.